# Gnome 3.8 / gdm / Failed to load session "gnome-classic"

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic, gdm

Installed gnome 3.8 from its official ppa. Installed gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions and ubuntu-gnome-desktop.

Installation went smooth. Also selected gdm as the login manager. THe only thing that doesnt work is when I select from the login window "gnome-classic" , press login, quickly throws with "Failed to load session "gnome-classic".

OS: ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Select "GNOME", that is the gnome-shell, "gnome-classic" is the fallback mode (gnome-panel).

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Classic, also known as the fallback session, was [dropped from GNOME 3.8](https://live.gnome.org/ThreePointSeven/Features/DropOrFixFallbackMode). It will not work unless you downgrade to GNOME 3.6.

Comment: Gnome classic is a new mode in Gnome 3.8. This replaces fallback.

Comment: @Hrr okay, i knew they had a collection of extensions to replace fallback's _look_ (right?). is this accessible as a separate session config?

Comment: yes. Available for selection during login